Date conversion not working properly in flutter app on release version
Date conversion in debug mode working fine in my flutter app but on release version its showing different values, even when I tried to show the exact value what was in Firestore on release version its showing different values in UI.
Here is the function I'm using to convert time
String utcToLocalTime(Timestamp firestoreTimestamp) {
  DateTime utcDateTime = firestoreTimestamp.toDate();
  final Duration offset = DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset;
  DateTime localDateTime = utcDateTime.add(offset);
  DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a');
  final timeZoneName = DateTime.now().timeZoneName;
  return '${dateFormat.format(localDateTime)} $timeZoneName';
}


Why are you doing retrieving DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset and doing DateTime localDateTime = utcDateTime.add(offset); instead of just var localDateTime = utcDateTime.toLocal();?

utcDateTime.toLocal(); not working so I tired in different way

Can you elaborate on "not working" means?  Can you provide an example for what value utcDateTime is, what your local timezone is, and what you expected output is?

Also, looking at the Timestamp.toDate implementation, firestoreTimestamp.toDate() should already return a local DateTime, not a UTC DateTime.

I have date "9 April 2024 at 04:36:00 UTC-7" like this in firestore, I want to display it as 2024-04-09 06:06 PM IST. its working currectly in debug but in release I'm getting 2024-04-09 06:06 AM IST instead of PM I'm getting AM. Even when I tried to show UTC its not working, getting some different date in release verison

"9 April 2024 at 04:36:00 UTC-7" would be 2024-04-09 11:36:00 UTC.  IST (assuming you mean India Standard Time) is UTC+5:30, so that would be 2024-04-09 5:06:00 PM IST, not 6:06 PM IST.  What does debugPrint(firestoreTimestamp.toDate()) show?  Is the device you're running on using IST?

I'm doing development in PST zone. Testing in IST time zone. What I did't understand is everything working fine in debug version but failing in release version

There should be no difference between debug and release versions.  There will be a difference between running on a system in PST (or currently more likely PDT) and a system running in IST.  Did you run the debug version on your test (IST) system?  firestoreTimestamp.toDate() will already be in the system's local time.  Adding any further offsets to that DateTime object is wrong. DateTime can represent either a time in the system's local time or a UTC time.  If you want to store a time in a timezone different than the local one, you should use TZDateTime from package:timezone.

Can you please give me code to convert "9 May 2024 at 10:00:00 UTC-7" this firebase timestamp to device local time

As I said before,firestoreTimestamp.toDate() already returns a local DateTime.  You should not need to do anything else.
